# Show only number before decimal in calculated column without rounding the number

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

*Application : SharePoint 2013*

I need to show only part of number before decimal nn calculated field that is looking on number column. And Calculated column results should be shown without rounding numbers.

Example:

```
Number column | Calculated column
   15,6781             15
   5,78                 5
   4,11                 4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, `=ROUNDDOWN([Column1],0)` should work nicely. See - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: The second parameter specifies the number of decimals and is 0 by default so you can leave it out. Note that the MSDN page has some minor mistakes in the examples. ROUNDDOWN(-5.9) is not -6 More: http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List